# Shimano Dura Ace FC7900 crankset with 11 speed group?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, crankset

I have a Dura ace FC7900 crankset and was wondering If I can use it on a bicycle with ultegra 11 speed group?

The crankset I have is this one:
http://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/shimano-dura-ace-crankset-fc-7900-53-39-170mm-31545

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The FC7900 crankset is from a 10 speed group.

[Nobody's going to stop you](http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/10/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-electronic-shifting-delivers-a-national-champion_306219) from doing this and having it work -- Zinn has done it and claims that it works. Manufacturers will [will say otherwise](http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/11/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-follow-up-on-10-and-11-speed-compatibility_307163) claiming weaker FD springs or very slightly different chainring spacing.

Since you already have the crankset, may as well put it in and try it if you want to use it.

Comment: the thing is I removed it from my 10 speed bike and I am selling it (  changing everything to 11 speed) but I have someone who is interested in buying it and wants to know if its compatible with a 11 speed ultegra

Comment: If it worked with 11 speed, why wouldn't you have used it on the bike you just converted to 11 speed?

Answer (score 2):

Shimano says "No, it is not compatible". If you are using it personally, perhaps it would be worth trying, but it can't be sold as 11 speed compatible.

Comment: For what it's worth , almost all Shimano equipped bikes are running something Shimano says is incompatible.

Comment: Ummmm, no. That's just not true. Where'd you get your data?

Comment: Anything that mixes non-Shimano parts?

Comment: @zenbike It's absolutely true. Look at spec lists for bikes.

Comment: @Batman, like what? Show me something that describes what you are saying.

Comment: @ NathanKnutson: Give me an example.  I can look at spec lists all day long, and I'm not going to find a stock bike using SHIMANO shifters for SRAM derailleurs, as an example. If you mean bikes using cranksets made by FSA or another brand with SHIMANO chains, etc... Yes, that happens. But they are FSA made cranks designed for that SHIMANO system, not mixing parts from different generations of kit, which is what we're talking about here. And while FOR MY OWN USE I might use a 10 speed crank on an 11 speed drivetrain for expedience, I would not sell it as compatible to someone else. It's fraud.

Comment: It's not fraudulent to say something is compatible if it works. It's only fraud when you know it doesn't work and say it does. FWIW I run a 5800 105 11 Spd crankset on a 6700 Ultegra 10 speed drivetrain and it works perfectly. I also run a XT/X9 9 Spd drivetrain on my hard tail which also runs perfectly.

Comment: Great. And if you sold those items, and told the user they were compatible, and the user went and looked up SHIMANO or SRAMs data on the matter, they would have grounds to sue, legally. Making a false statement to sell a product = fraud.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you said "The manufacturer says they don't work, but I've never had an issue", well that would be another story.